# How to pause a console c++ application when it finished in Visual studio code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I want to pause the console c++ program after it finished to watch its result.
I can't find any attribute launch configuration to pause my program.
Here is my code in launch.json.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(Windows) build and launch",
            "type": "cppvsdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: One option is to read dummy input before returning from `main()`. (You might surround it by `#ifdef _DEBUG` and `#endif` if not intended for release.) The other option is to run with [Ctrl]+[F5].

Comment: I found a lot of possible duplicates with [google "pause console after execution in VSCode site:stackoverflow.com"](https://www.google.com/search?q=pause+console+after+execution+in+VSCode+site:stackoverflow.com) but none with an accepted answer...

Answer (score 4):

thanks for your help.
here's my solution:
i run a cmd within the command to run my program and pause when its done

```
    {
        "name": "(Window) build and run",
        "type": "cppvsdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        "program": "cmd",
        "args": [
            "/k", 
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "&",
            "pause",
            "&",
            "exit"
        ],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true
    }
```

Comment: Hint: \` is for code embedded in text. Code blocks may be indented. There is a button [{}] in the toolbar for this.

Answer (score 1):

Put a breakpoint at the end of `main()`:

[image]

Then run under debugger (<kbd>F5</kbd>). It'll stop just before program exit.

Comment: That's a cool trick. I needed to put the break point at the last line and press F10 to make it work though.

Answer (score 0):

`system("pause");`    //this is what I use

`cin.get();`    //you can use this, but when you press ENTER, the console closes, if you enter a variable it is not a good solution

Comment: Please, see my notes about `system(pause)`. [SO: Why doesn't my program output the information I want in outside of Visual Studios 2019?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55676764/7478597) ;-)